# Linking jquery functions to PHP query results

Tags: php, jquery

Using PHP I am retrieving a list of videos.  I am using jquery to display the video in an overlay.  I have everything working, but the problem is the method of implementation seems a little brute force to me and I am looking for a way to cut out the redundant code.

Basically I get a list of videos from the database and output those using a foreach loop to the screen.  I use the ID of the video to make the **like** link id for each result unique:

```
<a id=like<?php echo $video['fileID'] ?>" ...
```

I then have to add the jquery to each iteration of the loop.  Its an ajax call that passes the information about the video, the current user, etc.  If the current user votes for a video then the jquery ajax function is called and a new vote count is displayed:

```
//upVote for a discussion
    $('#like<?php echo $video['fileID'] ?>').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'/ajax/likeFile.php',
        data:"voter=" + <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ? $_SESSION['user_id'] : ''); ?>
        + "&poster=" + <?php echo $video['userID'] ?>
        + "&classID=" + <?php echo $_SESSION['class'] ?>
        + "&lessonID=" + <?php echo $_SESSION['lesson'] ?>
        + "&id=" + <?php echo $video['fileID'] ?>
        + "&type=like",
        success: function(data) {
        var $response=$(data);
        var votes = $response.filter('#voteCount').text();
        $('#fileVotes').text(votes);
        $('#like').attr('src', '/images/upvoteDisabled.png');
        $('#unlike').attr('src', '/images/downvote.png');
        }

    });
    });
```

Like I said, this is working fine.  The problem is that I would like to cut down on repeating the jquery over and over for each link.  Is there a way to call this and just have the item that gets selected pass its current loop iteration variables instead of having create a jquery function for each link?

This is a really convoluted question I know.  Thanks in advance to anyone who wants to tackle this.

Comment: I'm assuming that the code that outputs this only appears once in your actual php code, right? If so, you're really not going to save yourself anything except a very minimal amount of bandwidth by making some sort of a javascript function to output the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, set an HTML5 DOCTYPE so you can take advantage of [custom data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Then have PHP populate your data attributes for each anchor:

```
<a class="like-btn" id="like<?=$video['fileID']?>" data-voter="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ? $_SESSION['user_id'] : '');" data-poster="<?=$video['userID']?>" data-class="<?=$_SESSION['class']?>" data-lesson="<?=$_SESSION['lesson']?>" data-file="<?=$video['fileID']?>"> ... </a>
```

Then use a single JQuery click handler:

```
$('a.like-btn').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'/ajax/likeFile.php',
        data:"voter="  + $(this).data('voter')
        + "&poster="   + $(this).data('poster')
        + "&classID="  + $(this).data('class')
        + "&lessonID=" + $(this).data('lesson')
        + "&id="       + $(this).data('file')
        + "&type=like",
        success: function(data) {
            var $response=$(data);
            var votes = $response.filter('#voteCount').text();
            $('#fileVotes').text(votes);
            $(this).attr('src', '/images/upvoteDisabled.png');
            //$('#unlike').attr('src', '/images/downvote.png'); // fix in your DOM
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of passing all this `$_SESSION` data around.  If it's stored in the session, it will be available on the server side and there is no reason to include it in the data attributes and the data that is sent in the Ajax request.  I would remove it to reduce complexity.

Comment: I'd change the selector to
   
     $('a.like-btn')

prefixing it with the tag will be quicker. Maybe not noticeable on a small set of results but better for larger result sets as document.getElementsByTagName (which is what it does under the hood) is quicker then filtering on classes. Also if you can add in a context selector that would improve it as well (context selector would be an id of an element that surrounds all the links)

Comment: @pifantastic absolutely, hadn't really thought about it until you said something.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use custom attributes and a class for your jQuery selector?

```
<a class="like"
   data-fileID="<?php echo $video['fileID'] ?>"
   data-userID="<?php echo $video['userID'] ?>">Like</a>
```

Then, you can:

```
$('a.like').click(function(){
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:'/ajax/likeFile.php',
    data:"voter=" + <?php echo (
         isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ? $_SESSION['user_id'] : ''); ?>
    + "&poster=" + $(this).data('userID')
    + "&classID=" + <?php echo $_SESSION['class'] ?>
    + "&lessonID=" + <?php echo $_SESSION['lesson'] ?>
    + "&id=" + $(this).data('fileID')
 ...
```

Prefixing the attribute with `data-` will make it HTML5 forward-compatible, and if you need to validate for previous versions of XHTML, just extend the DTD:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
[
  <!ATTLIST a data-fileID CDATA #IMPLIED>
  <!ATTLIST a data-userID CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
```

Comment: Instead of `$(this).attr('data-userID')` he can use `$(this).data('userID')`

Comment: @AlienWebguy, Nice. Proof that you learn something new every day. I'll be sure to use that in the future.

Comment: No prob :) With JQuery it seems to be several things every day though haha. That library is full of nifty tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generating the JavaScript code on the fly, generate a PHP array, transform it to a native JavaScript data type using json_encode(). In JavaScript you loop trough the data binding the click event. It will be easier and you won't need to create special HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

Give a class to all elements upon which vote up function should be triggered on clicking. Then it would be something like

```
    e.g. that is an anchor element with voteup class
    $('.voteup').click(function(){
         var fileid = $this.attr('id');
         //update $video['fileid'] with fileid
         //the code to update a specific class element can be implemented with this approach as well
    })
```